# DB rows need to take in columns

Tags: mysql

I have a below MySQL table.

```
id       Creation_Date         Goals  Alternative    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   2014-04-17 10:09:30     G1      A        0.86
2   2014-04-17 10:09:30     G1      B        0.87
3   2014-04-17 10:09:30     G2      A        0.5
4   2014-04-17 10:09:30     G2      B         0
```

I need a MySQL query for  changing rows in columns and also need to their respective values like below.

**Output Require **

```
Alternative     G1         G2  
------------------------------- 
   A           0.86        0.50
   B           0.87        0
```

**Tried Solution :**

I tried below query

```
select Alternative , max(case when Goals = 'G1' then round(value,2) end) as Goal1, max(case when Goals = 'G2' then round(value,2) end) as Goal2 from sgwebdb.dim_module group by id ;
```

but this is not giving required output ,this is giving below output

```
Alternative     G1         G2  
------------------------------- 
   A         0.86         Null
   B         0.87         Null
   A     Null         0.50
   B     Null         0.00
```

Comment: I tried below query

select Alternative  , 
  max(case when Goals = 'G1' then round(value,2) end) as Goal1,
   max(case when Goals = 'G2' then round(value,2) end) as Goal2
    from sgwebdb.dim_module group by id  ;

but it is giving me duplicate column

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP's comment**:

> I tried below query but it is giving me duplicate column
>
> `select Alternative , max(case when Goals = 'G1' then round(value,2) end) as Goal1, max(case when Goals = 'G2' then round(value,2) end) as Goal2 from sgwebdb.dim_module group by id ;`

---

You have to group by `alternative` for `goals` being converted to column based on `alternative`

**Query**:

```
select 
 alternative,
 max( case when goals='G1' then round( value, 2 ) end ) as 'G1',
 max( case when goals='G2' then round( value, 2 ) end ) as 'G2'
from sgwebdb.dim_module
group by alternative
;
```

**Result**:

```
+-------------+------+------+
| Alternative | G1   | G2   |
+-------------+------+------+
| A           | 0.86 | 0.50 |
| B           | 0.87 | 0.00 |
+-------------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder ,this is giving desired output..

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
SELECT Alternative,
SUM(Val*(1-ABS(SIGN(Goals-1)))) AS G1,
SUM(Val*(1-ABS(SIGN(Goals-2)))) AS G2
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Alternative;
```

the table look like: change `G1 to 1` and `G2 to 2`

```
id       Creation_Date     Goals  Alternative    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    2014-04-17 10:09:30       1        A             0.86
2    2014-04-17 10:09:30       1        B             0.87
3    2014-04-17 10:09:30       2        A             0.5
4    2014-04-17 10:09:30       2        B             0
```

the result look like:

```
Alternative     G1         G2  
------------------------------- 
   A           0.86        0.50
   B           0.87        0
```

Comment: Ravinder ans is working fine and with that ans I don't need to do any changes.your one is also giving desired output but I need to do changes in rows with you ans.thanks